# crontab shows the mysql error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating the rails app with 'whenever' gem.

And I defined the function in the User model and I want to execute the function every 7am.
But my function is not executing correctly and it shows the error.

schedule.rb

```
set :output, 'log/crontab.log'

set :environment, :production

every 1.day, at: '7:00 am' do
   runner 'User.create_group'
end
```

crontab.log

```
/Users/michel/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.8/lib/mysql2/client.rb:89:in `connect': Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'appnorth_production' (Mysql2::Error)
```

here is my database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: appnorth_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: appnorth_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: appnorth_production
  username: appnorth
  password: <%= ENV['APPNORTH_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Does anyone help me?

Comment: Please post your `config/database.yml`

Comment: Thank you for comment. I added config/database.yml.

Comment: Try removing username and password under the default

Comment: it shows the same error...

Answer (score 0):

Please insert the following line to schedule.rb.
And, Could you try?

`job_type :runner, "export :environment_variable=:environment && cd :path && bin/rails runner ':task' :output"`

Comment: What does your crontab shows?

If you exec the following command, your crontab will be updated in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/michel` if you use ubuntu.

`bundle exec whenever --update-crontab`

I want to see it.

Could you try?